# is it possible to make Windows highlight the active window/app?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, window-focus

I've been working with Windows for a long time. A few years ago my work environment got us a second monitor to use. It was fantastic, my productivity went up. Love it!

However, there's one thing that I frequently mess up on and that's which is the active window/application in a dual monitor setup? I've struggled with this since Windows 7, 8/8.1 and now 10. Windows default behavior, which I like and am used to using, is to allow me to scroll one window (e.g.: the browser) even when it doesn't have the focus. I love that and make lots of use of it. Normally I'll start in an application, then need to look something up so I'll bring the browser up in the other monitor, do I search, go back to the app do some things there, go back to the browser and scroll the contents or without realizing it do something there, then turn my attention to the first monitor and start typing, thinking that I'm typing in the app on the first monitor. But no, I've actually just sent the browser to God only knows where, or wiped out lots of text in SQL Server Management Studio, ruining a stored procedure, or something else. Sometimes it doesn't harm much, other things its disastrous. I know I should know better. I know what's going on and why, but after a few years of doing this normally multiple times a day, I've finally gotten sick of my own mistakes. I don't know why I don't "remember" which app I last touched, but I don't. So when I start "typing" thinking I'm in one app, but am in fact in another, well you get the idea.

So does Windows have some setting somewhere that will highlight an app, regardless of what app it is, that is the active window/application? If it has that, what is that?

Comment: It does, by default. It always did... except every incarnation gets harder & harder to distinguish, with the new flat, kindergarten UI. You could try using a high contrast theme.

Comment: @Tetsujin "kindergarten UI" lol

Comment: @DavidPostill - call me Skeuomorphist if the shoe fits - but it's true ;-))

Comment: @Tetsujin I know. That's why I lolled :)

Comment: @DavidPostill -  I think they do it just so us oldies struggle. Have to be of the "type with your thumbs" generation to have good enough eyesight to distinguish it properly ;-)